# Typescript: Two functions take same parameters but have different return types

Tags: typescript

I have the following types defined:

```
type MyType = <T>(a: string, b: Record<string, MyFunction<T>>) => T
type MyFunction<T> = () => T
```

I want to create another type (`MyType2`) that takes the same parameters but returns `void`.

I don't wish to use the same type for both and have it return `T | void` because one function must return `T` and one must return `void`.

How can I achieve this with Typescript in a DRY way?

I'm convinced it's possible but I cannot figure it.

Comment: Does `type MyType2 = (...args: Parameters<MyType>) => void` meet your needs, or do you have some more code that would depend on `MyType2` also having a generic parameter like `T`?

Comment: That seem to work perfectly. Thank you! If you post it as an answer then I will mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse the parameter types in a function using the `Parameters` helper and spread syntax:

```
type MyType2 = (...args: Parameters<MyType>) => void
```

Note that this results in a function type  with an `unknown` instead of a generic function type with a type parameter:

```
(a: string, b: Record<string, MyFunction<unknown>>) => void
```

In this specific case that may not matter; I am not sure if there is a general way to do this which would output another generic function type with its own type parameter, but I suspect there is not, since Typescript does not support higher-[kinded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) types. However, there is a way to make both functions generic without repeating too much code, by defining the parameters seperately as a generic tuple type:

```
type MyParameters<T> = [a: string, b: Record<string, MyFunction<T>>]

type MyType = <T>(...args: MyParameters<T>) => T
type MyType2 = <T>(...args: MyParameters<T>) => void
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbIDwBUA+KAXigAoBKU4-AKDtElhAAUBDAJ3YFsJgInAM4FiZANrsAXFCHBOGZAHMANFABGMgEoRUWTgBNcchcrVwkaTDlGEAugybQ4+cNDKjyAOh9clQmTgObj4BYVFqElpGNxZXSAAmUihPHy8-AJZg3n5BESJI4gA3LAwDOiA)

Comment: Your first solution works correctly for my scenario, but I like the second solution because it is flexible enough to keep the type information. Thank you :)